# Best way to give options for starts with or contains in REST query

Tags: rest

I have a REST service that allows people to put in a course title as part of the query to get scores, but, sometimes they may want to get a group, such as Calculus% for Calc 1, 2 and 3.

But, what is the best way to give them an option that makes sense?

For example, I have *http://localhost/myrest/any/any/Calculus III*

where the first two parameters are student id and some grade category.

I don't think having *http://localhost/myrest/any/any/contains/Calculus III* is a good use as then I will need to force them to use *equals* if that is what they are looking for.

Another option is *http://localhost/myrest/any/any/Calculus%* or *http://localhost/myrest/any/any/%Calc%* is another option, but then you have removed the option to easily use **%** as an allowed character.

So, to give additional filtering options in a REST URL, what is the best (defined as simplest/most intuitive for the user) way to allow contains or starts with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your system, would the following query list all subjects in the grade category?
`http://localhost/myrest/any/any/`

If yes, then one option you can consider is extracting the non-exact subject name into a GET parameter. Thus without breaking the current logic where having a full name of the subject in the URL provides the score for that subject, you'd also have the ability to filter the list of subjects within the same grade category by means of the GET parameter.

For example:
`http://localhost/myrest/any/any/?search=Calculus*`

... could provide a result like this:

```
<subjects>
    <subject uri="/myrest/any/any/Calculus%20I">A</subject>
    <subject uri="/myrest/any/any/Calculus%20II">B</subject>
    <subject uri="/myrest/any/any/Calculus%20III">C</subject>
</subjects>
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to name parameters, and your example may be good for 'starts with', but does nothing for 'contained in'.  We have over 18k distinct courses, which is the difficulty.  I may be forced to do "?startswith=..." or "?contains=..." but that seems messy.

Comment: @James: yes, I agree that implementing startswith/contains/etc would be messy (regardless if it would be done in the URI or as a GET parameter). What I proposed above was meant as a pure search which would support wildcards, hence the parameter name. The reason why I was first asking if `/myrest/any/any` is giving you a list of subjects by default is because if it is, then it should be perfectly RESTful to filter/scale down the resultset by means of a GET parameter. Technically, it's the same thing as Google does with `google.com/search?q=lorem+ipsum`.

Comment: OK, now I better understand, and you approach may be useful for filtering. Thank you.